# Is it safe to ignore Android release warning message - "This App Bundle contains Java/Kotlin code, which might be obfuscated"?

Tags: android, google-play, release, obfuscation

I got the following warning on submitting the app to the play store.

[image]

I don't use `minifyEnabled = true` in my app. So, my code won't be obfuscated. Is it safe to ignore this warning? What is the worst outcome if I ignore this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the worst outcome if I ignore this?

it tells you this in the warnings you have, that if you leave it as is, it might be harder to understand crashes and ANR's, nothing more

More info [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?hl=en)